# CollectionView error: must pass a valid reuse identifier

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I am trying to use UICollectionView prototype cell from storyboard as we did for UITableView. But `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(:, forIndexPath:)` crash down the application throwing an error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a valid reuse
>   identifier to -[UICollectionView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]'

What's need to do for UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Just select your cell (CollectionViewCell) and set an identifier name for it in **Attributes Inspector**:

[image]

Then use the same identifier in code:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("item", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: That's weird I just tested here a simple implementation in a ViewController that's set as the Collection View DataSource and Delegate. Without the identifier specified in Attributes Inspector the app crashes in the method you are crashing but when I set the identifier the problem is solved. Remember to implement all required methods on Collection View DataSource and Delegate if you haven't yet. Hope you find a way to fix that.

Comment: Even I found `must pass a valid reuse identifier` this error for first time.